# Compressing a bunch of HTMLs into one PDF

Tags: html, linux, pdf, encoding

I have a lot of HTML files (webpages, saved with FireFox as one `<filename>.html` file and a `<filename>_files` directory with statics). How can i compress them into one large PDF file with just Linux command-line?

Note: each file has its own encoding. For example, some files could be encoded with UTF-8 while the others are encoded with latin-1.

I've found the `htmldoc` utilite, but it does not supports UTF-8 encoding (at least, the version from apt-get repos). So the question becomes this:

how can i (with or without changing files' encodings) compress them to the one large PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`iconv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) to convert encoding from UTF-8
2. Use [`htmldoc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htmldoc) to convert HTML to PDF
3. Use [`pdftk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftk) to merge PDFs